# Bijection function bw 2 infinite set

Tags: real-analysis

Show that $X$ is infinite iff there exists a proper subset $Y$ of $X$ which has the same cardinality as $X$.

I only need to know how to show if $X$ is infinite there exists $Y$ proper subset of $X$ that has the same cardinality as $X$.

I set $X=\{x_0,x_1,x_2,...\}$
then take $Y=X\backslash\{x_0\}$
clearly $Y$ is a proper subset of $X$, but I see that $X$ could be uncountable so I'm thinking that my set $X$ is not working here.
Could anyone please help me?

Comment: Suppose $X$ is an infinite set. Obviously, $X\neq\emptyset$. So, there exists an element $a_0\in X$ and $X\setminus\{a_0\}$ is also an infinite set (why?). Continuing this argument, we can see that there exists a proper countable subset $(a_k)_{k\geq 0}$ of $X$. Now, we construct the bijection $X\to X\setminus\{a_0\}$ by the inclusion map if $x$ is not of the form $a_k$ and $x=a_k\mapsto a_{k+1}$ otherwise.

Comment: Thank you I get it. How about the another implication, I am thinking to use contrapositive. Do you think will be helpful.

Comment: I think it's best to use contradiction. Suppose there exists a proper subset $Y$ of a set $X$ such that $|Y|=|X|$. We need to show that $X$ is infinite. Let us assume that $X$ is finite (say $|X|=n$) where $n$ is a non-negative integer. Then, $|Y|\leq n~\forall~Y\subseteq X$ with equality iff $Y=X$ (this is easy to show rigorously). So, by definition, a proper subset $Y\subset X$ has $|Y|\lt n$ and hence $|Y|\neq n=|X|$, a contradiction.